# How do I get the shortcode for an Instagram media item to later embed the picture?

Tags: api, caching, instagram

I'd like to display Instagram photos matching particular tags on my site. I don't see a way to search for all tags over all time, so I am implementing a timer that periodically checks [`/tags/tag-name/media/recent`](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/#get_tags_media_recent) for my desired tags. Then I am caching the `.id` attribute of any as-yet-unseen media, so I can still have access to that item if and when `/tags/tag-name/media/recent` no longer returns that item.

Now I am ready to embed the images on my site, but I think saving `.id` is mistaken. The second available embed endpoint - [`/p/shortcode/media`](http://instagram.com/developer/embedding/#media_redirect) - looks close. It issues a redirect to the image, which will suffice for my task, but it wants a 'shortcode', not an id.

How do I get this shortcode? There is no `.shortcode` attribute on the media objects returned from `/tags/tag-name/media/recent`. Should I use a regex to parse the `.link` attribute, assuming that the link will take the form `http://instagr.am/p/shortcode/`? Or is there a better technique to remember and later display images that match my desired tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preferring regex solution over `String.split`, this is what I ended up doing:

```
//expecting http://instagr.am/p/BWl6P/
var linkrx = /\/p\/([^\/]+)\/$/;
// find /p/, then 1 or more non-slash as capture group 1, then / and EOL
if(igPic.link.match(linkrx) !== null){
  var shortcode = igPic.link.match(linkrx)[1];
};
```

Comment: suppose you have post links as `https://instagram.com/p/BW16p/?taken-by=blah-blah` then use  linkrx = `/\/p\/([^\/]+)\//` for extracting shortcode.

Answer (score 1):

No other way, just use .split() from the link attribute. This will give you the shortcode:

```
link.split("/")[4]
```

Answer (score 1):

/p/([^/]+)(/.)*$
this pattern match also links like:
https://instagram.com/p/6H_CiIrdKn/?taken-by=7imet4
https://instagram.com/p/6H_CiIrdKn

Answer (score 1):

This will always return the **last component** of a path:

```js
'http://instagr.am/p/D/'.replace(/\/$/i, '').split("/").pop()
```

So `http://instagr.am/p/D/` becomes `D`

### tl;dr

1. Remove any trailing slash (`//$/i`, `a/b/c/` → `a/b/c`)
2. Split by `/` (`a/b/c` → `[a,b,c]`)
3. Get the last item in the `[a,b,c]` array (`.pop()`, `[a,b,c]` → `c`)